# Using Z3 to sample from a constrained space

Tags: z3, constraint-programming

I have a bunch of constraints on variables and I am looking for a way to efficiently sample across this constrained space. I tried out Z3 and it seems to be able to tell me if the space is non-trivial (i.e. if the constraints are satisfiable) but I don't see a way to get examples from the space, unless I am minimizing or maximizing something.

Am I missing something or is this just not what Z3 is for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Z3 can give you a model, i.e., one example of an assignment to the variables that satisfies the constraints (try the `(get-model)` command in SMT2 or `Solver.Model` in the .NET API (and similarly named ones in the other APIs)). You can then assert the negation of the model to force the solver to produce a different assignment for the next query. This kind of scheme is used by many applications, but it's not necessarily "efficient", but that really depends on what kind of sampling you're trying to achieve (e.g., Z3 models will not be distributed randomly across the search space).

Comment: Yes, I was looking for random sampling. I'll have to use something else. Any suggestions?

Comment: I was thinking about using a strategy around euclidean distance: after generating the first point, start an optimization to maximize the distance from your constants and the existing solutions. I'm hoping to do this in https://www.github.com/groostav/sojourn-cvg, on the java stack. The problem is the verbiage: the SMT2 lisp-like is _so much nicer_ than the java API, I'm having trouble navigating it. The result might be slow, but I'm hoping it'l create a kind of full-factorial bounding-box around the feasible region --not uniform distribution, but good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are techniques you can use to sample from SAT solution space.  See https://simons.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/docs/4393/moshevardi.pdf

It might be possible to implement some of those techniques on top of Z3.

There is also an [existing implementation of the UniGen algorithm for almost-uniform sampling of SAT solution space on github](https://github.com/shubham-goel/UniGen), but it is based on a different SAT solver, and not sure if it supports SMT solving.

EDIT: There seems to be SMT sampler based on Z3 here: https://github.com/RafaelTupynamba/SMTSampler